# What is the correct way to include columns via match in pivot_longer while manually excluding others?

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I want to match all columns in a pivot_longer that have the suffix `_choice`, except for the following columns: `politics_forced_choice, no_taxes_filed_choice, concealed_permit_choice`

My current approach is the following:

```
test = df %>%
  select(-c(politics_forced_choice, no_taxes_filed_choice, concealed_permit_choice)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("_choice"), names_to = "names", values_to = "values")
```

And then later adding those excluded columns back in.

However, I assume there has to be a way within the `cols` parameter to include regex matches, and then manually exclude some other columns... something like:

```
   cols = vars(matches("_choice"), -c(politics_forced_choice, no_taxes_filed_choice, concealed_permit_choice))
```

But I can't quite seem to wrap my head around the right idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works. It simply combines (`c()`) `matches` and the columns to remove.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(matches("_choice"), -c("a_choice", "b_choice")),
    names_to = "name",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>%
  head()
## A tibble: 6 x 6
#      X     Y a_choice b_choice name     value
#  <int> <int>    <int>    <int> <chr>    <int>
#1     1     1        1        1 c_choice     1
#2     1     1        1        1 d_choice     1
#3     2     2        2        2 c_choice     2
#4     2     2        2        2 d_choice     2
#5     3     3        3        3 c_choice     3
#6     3     3        3        3 d_choice     3
```

**Data**

```
df <- replicate(6, 1:5)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df) <- c("X", "Y", paste0(letters[1:4], "_choice"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. You can use logical combinations in your cols parameter.

```
   cols = ends_with("_choice") & 
                     !one_of("politics_forced_choice", "no_taxes_filed_choice",
                      "concealed_permit_choice")
```

Comment: Note that `one_of()` is superseded in favour of the more precise `any_of()` and `all_of()` selectors.